# Updating GeoJSON properties?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, json

Below is my `demand.js` file containing my geojson data:

```
var campus = {
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",     
            "id":"03",
            "properties": {
                "name": "ANG MO KIO",        
                "demand":"30"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [[[
                [103.866,1.37152],[103.862,1.36902],[103.861,1.36761],
                [103.858,1.36139],[103.858,1.36041],[103.857,1.35777],
                [103.856,1.35518],[103.856,1.35398],[103.856,1.35231],
                [103.855,1.35202],[103.854,1.3542],[103.852,1.35624],
                [103.849,1.35865],[103.845,1.3623],[103.844,1.36289],
                [103.842,1.36318],[103.84,1.36335],[103.837,1.36402],
                [103.835,1.36497],[103.831,1.36737],[103.831,1.36843],
                [103.831,1.36926],[103.832,1.36942],[103.832,1.37001],
                [103.832,1.37062],[103.833,1.37112],[103.833,1.3716],
                [103.833,1.3723],[103.833,1.37436],[103.834,1.3759],
                [103.834,1.37613],[103.835,1.37681],[103.835,1.37684],
                [103.836,1.37798],[103.834,1.381],[103.835,1.38121],
                [103.835,1.3814],[103.835,1.38167],[103.836,1.38199],
                [103.837,1.38406],[103.839,1.38606],[103.843,1.38912],
                [103.845,1.39041],[103.846,1.39135],[103.848,1.39194],
                [103.849,1.3922],[103.85,1.39244],[103.85,1.38615],
                [103.85,1.38403],[103.849,1.38206],[103.848,1.38064],
                [103.848,1.37963],[103.848,1.379],[103.848,1.37854],
                [103.849,1.37788],[103.852,1.37726],[103.855,1.37695],
                [103.857,1.37718],[103.861,1.37839],[103.863,1.37881],
                [103.866,1.37889],[103.867,1.3787],[103.868,1.37834],
                [103.872,1.37663],[103.869,1.37614],[103.869,1.37564],
                [103.867,1.37429],[103.867,1.37276],[103.866,1.37152]
                ]]]
            } 
        }
    ]
};

function setDemand(id, newdemand) {   
    for (var i=0; i<campus.length;i++) {
        if (campus[i].features.id > id) {
            campus[i].features.properties.demand = newdemand;
            return;
        } else {
            campus[i].features.properties.demand = newdemand+100;
        }     
    }    
}
```

The `setDemand` function is called when the select button is triggered:

```
<select onchange="setDemand(10,1000)">
```

But it does not work - the properties do not change. I am new to geoJSON/JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong,Try to use any HTML Editor Tool. You have additional bracket :

```
var campus = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{      
        "type": "Feature", "id": "03",
        "properties": {
            "name": "ANG MO KIO", "demand": "30"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                  [103.866, 1.37152], [103.862, 1.36902], [103.861, 1.36761], [103.858, 1.36139], [103.858, 1.36041], [103.857, 1.35777], [103.856, 1.35518], [103.856, 1.35398], [103.856, 1.35231], [103.855, 1.35202], [103.854, 1.3542], [103.852, 1.35624], [103.849, 1.35865], [103.845, 1.3623], [103.844, 1.36289], [103.842, 1.36318], [103.84, 1.36335], [103.837, 1.36402], [103.835, 1.36497], [103.831, 1.36737], [103.831, 1.36843], [103.831, 1.36926], [103.832, 1.36942], [103.832, 1.37001], [103.832, 1.37062], [103.833, 1.37112], [103.833, 1.3716], [103.833, 1.3723], [103.833, 1.37436], [103.834, 1.3759], [103.834, 1.37613], [103.835, 1.37681], [103.835, 1.37684], [103.836, 1.37798], [103.834, 1.381], [103.835, 1.38121], [103.835, 1.3814], [103.835, 1.38167], [103.836, 1.38199], [103.837, 1.38406], [103.839, 1.38606], [103.843, 1.38912], [103.845, 1.39041], [103.846, 1.39135], [103.848, 1.39194], [103.849, 1.3922], [103.85, 1.39244], [103.85, 1.38615], [103.85, 1.38403], [103.849, 1.38206], [103.848, 1.38064], [103.848, 1.37963], [103.848, 1.379], [103.848, 1.37854], [103.849, 1.37788], [103.852, 1.37726], [103.855, 1.37695], [103.857, 1.37718], [103.861, 1.37839], [103.863, 1.37881], [103.866, 1.37889], [103.867, 1.3787], [103.868, 1.37834], [103.872, 1.37663], [103.869, 1.37614], [103.869, 1.37564], [103.867, 1.37429], [103.867, 1.37276], [103.866, 1.37152]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
};

function setDemand(id, newdemand) {
    for (var i = 0; i < campus.length; i++) {
        if (campus.features[i].id > id) {
            campus.features[i].properties.demand = newdemand;
            return;
        }

        else {
            campus.features[i].properties.demand = newdemand + 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u specify where?I tried with an HTML editor but both seems same

Comment: @IvanSanchez fixed the code already, check the **Edited**

Answer (score 3):

Note that `campus` is **not** an array, so you can **not** do

```
campus[i]
```

Instead, `campus` is a plain javascript object with a `features` property which is an array, so you **can** do

```
campus.features[i]
```

In order to change a property of the *i*-th feature in a GeoJSON `FeatureCollection`, just

```
campus.features[i].properties.demand = newValue;
```

---

Your original question had a syntax error in the GeoJSON (an additional set of brackets). If you're new to GeoJSON and you are writing the GeoJSON structures by yourself, please use a tool like http://geojsonlint.com/ to make sure that the structures are valid.

Comment: I edited the code and ran the exact function but still the change is not happening

Comment: What "change" is not happening? How are you checking that it's not happening?

Comment: `function getColor(d) {
  return  d > 1000 ? '#4CA64C' :
    d > 500  ? '#6fdc6f' :
    d > 200  ? '#6fdc6f' :
    d > 100  ? '#6fdc6f' :
    d > 50   ? '#6fdc6f' :
    d > 20   ? '#6fdc6f' :
    d > 10   ? '#6fdc6f' :
         '#FFEDA0';
    
 }`             This code changes the color of each polygon according to it's demand properties

Comment: The properties of the GeoJSON are changing - this does **not** mean that values depending on the GeoJSON properties change *automatically*

Comment: no they do not change automatically.I trigger the map update functions to update the map according to the new properties.

Comment: That's the expected behaviour.